# Defining fabricator w/ file attachment & testing file upload w/ rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, carrierwave, fabrication-gem

I'm trying to figure out the how to test file attachments w/ the Fabrication and Rspec gems.  The file upload works fine when testing the site manually, there's just no Rspec coverage.  The problem seems to be that I don't know how to include an attachment in a PUT request.

How do I add a file attachment, preferably using a fabricator, to this test

Fabricator:

```
Fabricator(:application) do
  email      Faker::Internet.email
  name       Faker::Name.name
  resume_url { File.open(
    File.join(
      Rails.root,
      "spec",
      "support",
      "files",
      "hey_look_a_pdf_pdf_lolz.pdf"
      )
    )
  }
end
```

Controller:

```
class ApplicationsController < ApplicationController
    def update
    @application = Application.find_or_initialize_by(id: params[:id])

    if @application.update(application_params)
      flash[:success] = "Application has been saved :)"
      redirect_to application_path(@application)
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private

  def application_params
    params[:application].permit(:email, :job_id, :name, :resume_url)
  end
end
```

Controller test

```
require "spec_helper"

# this is a sample application attributes being passed into controller
# it should have a file attachment, but haven't figured out how to do that
#
# {
#   "id"=>"fa446fdf-b82d-48c0-8979-cbbb2de4fb47",
#   "email"=>"old@example.com",
#   "name"=>"Dr. Rebeca Dach",
#   "resume_url"=>nil,
#   "job_id"=>"cf66dbcf-d110-42cc-889b-0b5ceeeed239",
#   "created_at"=>nil,
#   "updated_at"=>nil
# }

describe ApplicationsController do
  context "PUT /applications/:id" do
    it "creates an application" do
      expect { put(
        :update,
        application: application.attributes,
        id:          application.id
      )}.to change{Application.count}.from(0).to(1)
    end
  end
end
```

## Update #1

The following Fabricator seems to work okay.  I'm still not able to get file attachments to work in controller tests.

```
Fabricator(:application) do
  email      Faker::Internet.email
  name       Faker::Name.name
  resume_url { ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new(
    tempfile: File.new(Rails.root.join(
      "./spec/support/files/hey_look_a_pdf_pdf_lolz.pdf"
    )),
    filename: File.basename(File.new(Rails.root.join(
      "./spec/support/files/hey_look_a_pdf_pdf_lolz.pdf"
    )))
  )}
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I got it figured out.  There were two pieces.

1)  I had to fix the Fabricator, which I mentioned in "Update #1" to my question.  Here's a simpler format for the Fabricator using Rack::Test::Upload.new

```
Fabricator(:application) do
  email      Faker::Internet.email
  name       Faker::Name.name
  resume_url {
    Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new(
      "./spec/support/files/hey_look_a_pdf_pdf_lolz.pdf",
      "application/pdf"
    )
  }
end
```

2)  I was using `Fabricator.build(:application).attributes`, which wasn't compatible with a file attachment.  Instead, I started using `Fabricator.attributes_for(:application)`, and everything started working great.  Here's the passing.

```
describe ApplicationsController do
  context "PUT /applications/:id" do
    let(:job) { Fabricate(:job) }

    let(:application) do
      Fabricate.attributes_for(
        :application,
        email:  "old@example.com",
        id:     SecureRandom.uuid,
        job_id: job.id
      )
    end

    it "creates an application" do
      expect { put(
        :update,
        application: application,
        id:          application["id"]
      )}.to change{Application.count}.from(0).to(1)
    end
  end
end
```